# Make tag helper work "button" like "a"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core I can set an action to a link item `a`, however if I change it to a button it doesn't work anymore.

What is the correct way to bind an action/controller to a **`button`** click?

```
<a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">remove</a> @*work*@
```

vs

```
<button asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">remove</button> @*does not work*@
```

Comment: Do you specifically want a `button` or have you considered CSS to make your link look like a button?

Comment: i would avoid `GET`s for a delete. You should `POST`

Comment: I would like to know if we could link a `button` to an action/controller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not that it does not work, they are different Tag Helpers with different usage:
If you hover over the `<a>` you will see it implements `AnchorTagHelper`, while the `<button>` implements the `FormActionTagHelper`, because it is supposed to be used in `<form>`s.

So, in order to get the same behavior, you would do this:

```
<a asp-action="Index">aaaa</a>

<form>
    <button asp-action="Index">bbbbb</button>
</form>
```

Note, though, that the button is rendered as `formaction="/"`, not as `href="/"`, and this is why you need to wrap it inside a form.
The second could also be written like this:

```
<form asp-action="Index">
    <button type="submit">bbbbb</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I have multiple rows of products, and I added a "delete" button in each row

Comment: What is the proper way of adding a "asp-route-id="value" " when using <button> inside a <form>?

Comment: @Mudo The `<button>` cannot have that. The `<form>` is the element that has the URL